# How to Compare string with integer in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my program I have to compare a string to the integer like

```
            temp=$(taskset -p $pid)
            if[ ${temp:35:1} -eq $cpu || ${temp:35:2} -eq $cpu ] ; then
```

Here I am comparing a substring from temp with integer cpu.
But when I run this script I get following error

line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
line 16:`                if[ ${temp:35:1} -eq $cpu || ${temp:35:2} -eq $cpu ] ; then'

How can I compare this string with integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` is for the shell, use `-o` for the test command:

```
if [ ${temp:35:1} -eq $cpu -o ${temp:35:2} -eq $cpu ]
```

You might replace the whole thing by

```
if [ $(taskset -p $pid|awk '{print $NF}') = $cpu ]
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what `taskset` returns and what the `cpu` variable contains. Answer updated anyway.

Comment: NF = number of fields, $NF = the value of the last field

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error.

```
if [ condition1 ] || [ condition2 ] && [ condition3 ] ; then
```

Answer (score 0):

to compare the value between an integer and a string you should compare the 2  vars inside double quotes:
    "$a" == "$b"